# Convergence that is slower than algebraic convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

all, suppose that 
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} r(t)=r_0>0, 
$$
I am wondering whether there exists $C>0$ and $\alpha>0$ such that
$$
|r(t)-r_0|\leq C(t+1)^{-\alpha},   \quad  \forall t>0. 
$$

If it were the case,  then algebraic convergence is the slowest convergence。

I thought the above claim was not right, but I did not find such a supporting example. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dear Guys, I found an example “algebraic-algebraic”:$r(t)=(1+\frac{1}{t})^{\frac{1}{t}}$

Answer (score 1):

We may consider $\lim r(t) =0$, because then $\lim (r(t)+r_0)$ will tend to $r_0$.

If we do not believe the statement, we should try to find a counter example, that is we need to find a function $r(t)$ such that 
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}r(t)=0$$
while
$$t^\alpha r(t)$$
is unbounded for all $\alpha$.

Does this help?